# How to connect Android App connecting to a web service

Tags: android

I created a small app and with this app I want to send the data (over wifi or bluetooth) to a PC/server.

1. I am thinking of creating a webservice that will run on the PC and will be listening constantly to any incoming client requests.
2. Once it receives request from client, the data transfer takes place.And after the webservice receives the data it should automatically open an application/GUI window showing the data received.

My question is Can I create a webservice using TCP/IP in JAVA and have it constantly run in background and listening to client request?
Also how do I start a GUI as soon as the webservice detects a client request and receives the data?

Comment: Yes, You can do this way. But when u continuous call web service, your performance of your application is become  very low.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use WS on the server-side and you can use [Ksoap android library](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) on the client-side. Create a background thread which updates the UI with the new data with. Use AsyncTask, Loader or Handler which is fit for your solution. (Read the [official reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) for more info).

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server to manage the data on your desktop and create a web-service in .NET on Visual Studio.

Then connect to the web-service in your application and set/get data from the DB, using web-services.

*Links which might be useful :*

**How to make a web-service in .NET (does not include the implementation in Android) :** http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx

**How to connect your service with Android :**

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap

http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to create a web service and connect your application to the web service, you can use the tool http://www.wsdl2code.com that create all the needed code for connecting and parsing the data :)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve this by creating an end-points/routes using node.js or php then host it on the cloud. I think I like firebase for hosting for now, u might wonna try that it really cool. after creating those endpoint which will be connected to ur database then u use http get or post request depending on what u want from ur database in ur mobile app.
if u are creating for android use Retrofit for http connection.