# How to consume the Soap webservices like below, in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, soap-client

I am beginner in Android. How I can consume the below web services in Android?

```
  POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
  Host: localhost
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: length
  SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/RegisterUser"

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <RegisterUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <userid>string</userid>
  <password>string</password>
  <cnic>string</cnic>
  <email>string</email>
 </RegisterUser>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <RegisterUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <RegisterUserResult>string</RegisterUserResult>
 </RegisterUserResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789451/how-to-connect-android-app-connecting-to-a-web-service